# Convert python string array to number

Tags: python, arrays

so I have the following problem:

`arr =["5","-2","4","C","D","9","+","+"]`
I need to convert the numbers both negative and non-negative to integers while mantaining the order of the array, the string and alphanumeric characters should remain as is

Here is my code so far

```
arr = ["5","-2","4","C","D","9","+","+"]
print(arr)
for i in arr:
  
  if i.isdigit() or  type(i) == int:
    print(int(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `try` and `except`

```
arr = ["5","-2","4","C","D","9","+","+"]

new = []
for data in arr:
    try:
        new.append(int(data))
    except ValueError:
        new.append(data)
print(new)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = ["5","-2","4","C","D","9","+","+"]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    try:
        arr[i] = int(arr[i])
    except ValueError:
        None
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[5, -2, 4, 'C', 'D', 9, '+', '+']
```

Answer (score 0):

The principle is to test the value, then reassign to the its index the `int` value, if exists

---

You could use some validation using a regex like

```
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    if re.fullmatch(r"-?\d+", val):
        arr[i] = int(val)
```

But the easiest statys the `try/except`

```
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    try:
        arr[i] = int(val)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```